# How to change an h3 to h2 only on specific pages with jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm coming across an issue for a client's side that they want to update the h3's to h2's on a couple pages and the data is coming from another source. So what I'm trying to do is change the h3 on the service and the resource pages to h2s. Right now I have the following which sort of but not really works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("services") > -1) {
       $('.u-label h3').replaceWith(function () {
          return $("<h2>", {
            "class",
            this.className,
            html: $(this).html();
          });
        });;
        }
      });
</script>
```

I thought in theory it should work but I'm getting unexpected token on the comma after class. Am I even close with this? Is there a better/cleaner way of getting the h3 to h2?

Comment: `"class": this.className, html: $(this).html()'

Comment: Wouldn't it be just easier to style `h3` same as `h2` using CSS?

Comment: Styling honestly has nothing to do with it. Dealing with accessibility so it's reading from h1 to h3 for screen readers. To be compliant it has to go from h1 to h2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should yield the same results while using the [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) function a little bit differently.

I'm also not sure if the data you are passing in is valid. If you read the docs from jQuery (link above) regarding the `replaceWith` function and the allowed paramter:

> May be an HTML string, DOM element, array of DOM elements, or jQuery object.

You are passing a hybrid of an array and an object. Even if you were passing an array, it would need to be an array of DOM elements and not meta data like you are doing currently.

---

I chose to find all of the targeted DOM elements and iterate through them one-by-one.

Here's a working fiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/2jkqh34n/

You can also access all of the current DOM elements data while iterating through them. I have supplied examples in the code, but not the fiddle.

### HTML

```
<div class="scope">
    <div class="change-these">
        <h2 class="sm">foo</h2>
        <h2 class="md">bar</h2>
        <h2 class="lg">baz</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="omit-these">
        <h2>foo</h2>
        <h2>bar</h2>
        <h2>baz</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.scope .change-these h2').each(function (i, el) {
        var c = $(el).attr("class");
        $(el).replaceWith('<h3 class="'+ c +'">' + $(el).html() +'</h3>')
    });
});
```

#### This will yeild

```
<div class="scope">
    <div class="change-these">
        <h3 class="sm">foo</h3>
        <h3 class="md">bar</h3>
        <h3 class="lg">baz</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="omit-these">
        <h2>foo</h2>
        <h2>bar</h2>
        <h2>baz</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects in JavaScript must contain key-value pairs. In your case you have the object:

```
{
    "class",              // Not a key-value pair.
    this.className,       // Not a key-value pair.
    html: $(this).html(); // Is a key-value pair, but should not have a semi-colon.
}
```

To fix it, you will need to do something like the following:

```
{
    class: this.className,
    html: $(this).html()
}
```

These changes may or may not be exactly what you're looking for, but the general idea remains the same.

Comment: `class` is a keyword in JavaScript, so it needs to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This code should not recreate any `h3` child elements. That means if you have any events or jQuery data bound to those child elements they should still work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("services") > -1) {
       $('.u-label h3').each(function () {
          var $h3 = $(this);
          var $h2 = $("<h2>").attr('class', $h3.attr('class')).append($h3.contents());
          $h3.replaceWith($h2);
       });
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are creating a JavaScript object which is expected to have combination of key value pairs. These key value pairs need to be separated by colon (:)

So the code would look like this:

```
$("<h2>", { "class" : this.className,
        html: $(this).html()
      });
```

Comment: Those aren't angular brackets, those are HTML chars.

Comment: No, the angle brackets are necessary to distinguish the creation of an element from the selection of one. With angle brackets, a new element is created; without, it is a selector.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yeah thanks for that. I modified the code accordingly.